# Updating XML node using XSLT

Tags: xslt

```
<Instance xsi:type="ButtonConfig">
    <Name>ExitButton</Name>
    <Height>89</Height>
    <Width>120</Width>
    <Margin>
        <All>-1</All>
        <Bottom>0</Bottom>
        <Left>400</Left>
        <Right>0</Right>
        <Top>11</Top>
     </Margin>        
</Instance>
```

In the above xml, I need to change the Left Margin to 420. How do I do it using XSLT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost the “[identify transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform)”, which simply duplicates the input document.

Here’s a simple stylesheet that mostly performs the identity transform, while overriding the output for a `<Left/>` within a `<Margin/>` within an `<Instance/>` that has a `<Name/>` containing `ExitButton`. Note that I had to add a namespace definition to your input XML for `xsi`, which I assume is elsewhere in the document.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Margin/Left[ancestor::Instance/Name[text()='ExitButton']]">
    <Left>420</Left>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The Instance node is repated multiple times. The Name is unique in each Instance node.

Comment: @WPFLearner: that’s the kind of detail you should give in your question, then! I updated the stylesheet to match the particular name.

Comment: You’re welcome. If you mark the question as answered, other people will know you no longer need advice.

Answer (score 3):

As any XSLT tutorial would tell you: For something simple like this, start with the identity stylesheet, which copies the document essentially unchanged... then add a template which implements the exception to that.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Margin/Left">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:text>420</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The Instance node is repated multiple times. The Name is unique in each Instance node.

Comment: Improve your question, then, so we have enough detail to answer the question. Or start with what I've sketched and expand upon it.